# Recommendation to manage multiple lifecycle nodes

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I imagine a scenario in which there are states, such as standby, hovering, and landing, and each one of these states corresponds to a certain set of active LifecycleNodes. Let's say A, B, and C for standby; D, E, and A for hovering and F, G, and H for landing. It is important to guarantee that in each state the respective nodes will be correctly set and as fast as possible. It may also be necessary to reload parameters.

Questions:

Any recommendations on how to do that and deal with possible state transition failures?
Are there plans to create a ROS2 native node/tool to manage multiple lifecycle nodes and perform that sort of task?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/341887/recommendation-to-manage-multiple-lifecycle-nodes/) by [ignacio](https://answers.ros.org/users/45287/ignacio/) on ROS Answers with karma: 68 on 2020-01-16

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2020-01-16**:
What good timing, I just posted a ticket trying to suss out some of the same topics: https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/issues/1472. I think we're in early days of lifecycle nodes (and even just people understanding them enough to use them) and there's a lot of room for improvement. I would like to hear the answer to your question as well from folks that might be more directly involved in that sort of thing, but I think it would also be valuable in this question to add what types of things you might want in this tool to help build design requirements (or be involved building yourself :-) ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your description reminds me of what the [system_modes](https://github.com/micro-ROS/system_modes) package created by Bosch was created for.

It essentially almost recursively applies the lifecycle management concept and allows you to configure the *mode* of a system (your *states*) through a relatively high-level interface, controlling all required nodes and their individual life-cycles for you.

See the [system_modes_examples](https://github.com/micro-ROS/system_modes/tree/315e4954e5148245c3b99694a019e5719b0899c5/system_modes_examples) package for a nice example of how this all works and what it can do.

An alternative could be using behaviour trees, but those would not have support for the domain concepts directly (but would be capable of managing this sort of thing).

Some (related) links:

- [Lifecycle and System Modes](https://micro-ros.github.io/docs/concepts/client_library/system_modes) in the Micro-ROS documentation
- [Lifecycle and System ModesSoftware Release Y1](http://ofera.eu/storage/deliverables/M12/OFERA_44_D4.8_Lifecycle_and_system_modes_software_release_Y1.pdf), Deliverable 4.8 of the Ofera project

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-01-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ignacio](https://answers.ros.org/users/45287/ignacio/) on 2020-01-27**:
That is very useful. Thank you very much! This package seems to change the node state accordingly.
I still have one concern regarding state transition failure, though. Is it possible to try to change from inactive to active and it just doesn't change. I ask that because I couldn't find any control that guarantees that my node will change its state.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-01-28**:
I would advise you to ask the authors/maintainers of that package. I'm not one of them.

**Comment by [ignacio](https://answers.ros.org/users/45287/ignacio/) on 2020-01-28**:
Could you help me to do that? I don't know how to reach them. Should I ask as a form of Issue on Github?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-01-28**:
Yes. Post an issue on their tracker.

**Comment by [ralph-lange](https://answers.ros.org/users/39505/ralph-lange/) on 2020-01-29**:
If a node does not switch from inactive to active, then the mode monitor of the system modes package will detect this discrepancy between target state and actual state. The provided mode inference mechanism allows to query this state even from another application node (e.g., inside some task execution state machine or behavior tree). Furthermore, we are currently working on a simple rules mechanism to define recovery behaviors for such cases.

**Comment by [ralph-lange](https://answers.ros.org/users/39505/ralph-lange/) on 2020-01-29**:
Please find another example for the use of the system modes concept (besides the integrated example in the system modes repo) at https://github.com/MROS-RobMoSys-ITP/Pilot-URJC. This demo shows the runtime reconfiguration of the whole Navigation2 stack using system modes. As a teaser, you may watch the video at https://youtu.be/PTyfaGybxl8

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As mentioned by gvdhoorn and ralph, system modes might be of help for you. They provide a hierarchy abstraction (systems of systems of nodes) and a mode-manager that manages state and mode of these entire (sub-)systems.
See [system_modes](https://github.com/micro-ROS/system_modes/) package and its [examples](https://github.com/micro-ROS/system_modes/tree/master/system_modes_examples).

We also intend to provide rules to deal with the case that a node or system is not in its intended state/mode. I just [created an issue](https://github.com/micro-ROS/system_modes/issues/13) with our first basic thoughts on that.

Love to hear your thoughts and feedback!

---

Originally posted by [Arne Nordmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/39498/arne-nordmann/) with karma: 28 on 2020-02-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ignacio](https://answers.ros.org/users/45287/ignacio/) on 2020-02-12**:
Thank you for all your comments and responses! We are currently trying to integrate the boost state chart to our action server, which will trigger all system-modes client calls. For now, the system_modes package is doing great.

We will definitely keep this thread open giving feedback! Would you rather receive them on these open issues or
here (ros.answers)?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-02-12**:
As ROS Answers is a Q&A site which works best with a 1-to-1 ratio of questions-to-answers, I would suggest you accept the answer provided to you and move any discussion or further feedback to a more appropriate place.